# Multilanguage PHP contact form, is it possible?

Tags: php, multilingual

i have contact form implemented on my website. Recently i decided to make the page multilanguage. Everything works finu, but i don't know how to implement it in contact form messages that will pop-up after sending an email. There is example how it's originally written:

```
if(empty($_POST["userName"])) {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> We are sorry but Your name is too short.'));
        die($output);
    }
```

and I want to change the text "We are sorry but Your name is too short." with echo to my language php file, here's example:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($lang['warning']);
```

in lang.php file there is:

```
$lang["warning"] = "We are sorry but Your name is too short.";
```

is it somehow possible please ? Thanks for any advices :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply concatenating the strings should work:

```
if(empty($_POST["userName"])) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<i class="icon ion-close-round"></i> ' . htmlspecialchars($lang['warning'])));
    die($output);
}
```